# Excel Repeat Items Of Col C as Per Col B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have products data where I need to multiploy values of col C as Per col B and A. An example will make it easier to understand so:

```
Product Name                   Category                       Part
Adjustable-Thermostats_226     Glasswashers/Classeq Eco 2     30000971
Air-Break---Type-B_227         Glasswashers/Classeq Eco 2     3501194
                               Dishwashers/Classeq Hydro 400  30001056
                                                              61004430
                                                              61004451
Air-Pressure-Vessel_229        Glasswashers/Classeq Eco 2     30001077
                               Glasswashers/Classeq Duo 2     30001765
                               Dishwashers/Classeq Hydro 400  60000008
                               Dishwashers/Classeq DUO 400    60000009
                                                              30001068
```

I need a formula that returns values:

```
Adjustable-Thermostats_226        Glasswashers/Classeq Eco 2    3501194
Air-Break---Type-B_227            Glasswashers/Classeq Eco 2    30001056
                                  Glasswashers/Classeq Eco 3    61004430
                                  Glasswashers/Classeq Eco 4    61004451
                                  Dishwashers/Classeq Hydro 400 30001056
                                  Dishwashers/Classeq Hydro 401 61004430
                                  Dishwashers/Classeq Hydro 402 61004451
Air-Pressure-Vessel_229           Glasswashers/Classeq Eco 2    30001077
                                  Glasswashers/Classeq Eco 2    30001765
                                  Glasswashers/Classeq Eco 2    60000008
                                  Glasswashers/Classeq Eco 2    60000009
                                  Glasswashers/Classeq Eco 2    30001068
                                  Glasswashers/Classeq Duo 2    30001077
                                  Glasswashers/Classeq Duo 2    30001765
                                  Glasswashers/Classeq Duo 2    60000008
                                  Glasswashers/Classeq Duo 2    60000009
                                  Glasswashers/Classeq Duo 2    30001068
                                  Dishwashers/Classeq Hydro 400 30001077
                                  Dishwashers/Classeq Hydro 400 30001765
                                  Dishwashers/Classeq Hydro 400 60000008
                                  Dishwashers/Classeq Hydro 400 60000009
                                  Dishwashers/Classeq Hydro 400 30001068
                                  Dishwashers/Classeq DUO 400   30001077
                                  Dishwashers/Classeq DUO 400   30001765
                                  Dishwashers/Classeq DUO 400   60000008
                                  Dishwashers/Classeq DUO 400   60000009
                                  Dishwashers/Classeq DUO 400   30001068
```

Could anyone help please?

Comment: Explain the logic to get it. How the data increasing in output?

Comment: So if there are 2 categories for a product, the parts against that product shoud repeat. e.g. if product A has 2 Categories B & C and 3 parts XYZ, it should repeat like B X, B Y, B Z then C X, CY, C Z

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest solution:

- add an automatic filter to the first row;
- in the first empty row of Category column write = the cell above (if B5 is the first empty cell use `=B4`)
- copy the formula aboce (B5) in all the empty cells

[image: example of formula you have to use]